# JUNIT won't able to display any success data, but JUnit Test case is passing sucessfully

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit4

I am new to Junit world,please let me know for below issue what might be the case
even though i missing ;(semicolon) test case are being passed successfully

Please look below code snippet

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DataBaseConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@Ignore
public class BlogTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private Blog blogManager;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Session session = Utils.getSessionFromEntityManger(entityManager);
    }
    @Test
    public void addBlogTest() {
        try {
            LoggedInUser loggedInUser = new LoggedInUser();
            loggedInUser.setTenantOID(1);
            loggedInUser.setUserID(1);
            loggedInUser.setSessionId("Sadasdas");
            Blog blog = new Blog();

            blog.setBlogName("WindowsTALKEE");
            blog.setCreatedByID(1);
            blogManager.addBlog(blog, loggedInUser);

            System.out.println("Successfully inserted");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: In your method `addBlogTest` it is not clear what you want to test. There are no assertions.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `@Ignore`.
`@Ignore` ignores the whole test class.
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Ignore.html